# Помощь в реализации регулярных автобусных рейсов

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Пишу проект, в котором нужно реализовать рейсовые автобусы с определенным промежутком времени. В базе данных хранится дата рейса и промежуток в днях и детали рейса. Проблема в том, что я не знаю как сделать именно регулярное добавление записи в бд с этим рейсом через тот промежуток в днях. Создавать сразу допустим 20 штук, так они когда-нибудь закончатся, не очень автономно выходит. Очереди сразу отпадают, так как они не работают на сервере :( Посоветуйте пожалуйста, что можно сделать, и если возможно максимально детально! Буду очень благодарен! Фреймворк - laravel 8, БД - mysql.

Comment: Event Procedure, которая выполняется, например, ежедневно, и создаёт необходимое количество записей на достаточный будущий период, если они отсутствуют. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html

Comment: Спасибо большое! Это мне и нужно было.